# Removing legend items without specifying the layer group with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

How can I remove multiple layers from legend in the MapComposer without removing them from the canvas and without having to specified their group ?

In the code below I have to add `group = root_group.findGroup("group_name_1")` to remove the layers belonging to this group but I would like to find a way to remove the layers without having to indicate their group name... Is it possible ?

```
layers_to_remove = []

legend = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemLegend)][0]
root_group = legend.model().rootGroup()  
group = root_group.findGroup("group_name_1")  
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)
for layer in layers_to_remove:
    root_group.removeLayer(layer)
```

Comment: All layers have unique names?

Comment: Yes they only have unique names !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the group dynamically by getting the name of the layer's parent in the layer tree:

```py
# reference to the project
p = QgsProject.instance()

# names of layers to remove from legend
layers_to_remove = ['layer1', 'layer2']

# the layer tree
root = p.layerTreeRoot()

# layout manager
manager = p.layoutManager()

# first layout (can also use manager.layoutByName() )
layout = manager.layouts()[0]

# get legend
legend = [i for i in layout.items() if isinstance(i, QgsLayoutItemLegend)][0]

# disable auto-update
legend.setAutoUpdateModel(False)

# legend model
model = legend.model()

# the root legend group
root_group = model.rootGroup()

# loop through layer names
for layer_name in layers_to_remove:
    # find layer in project
    layer = p.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    
    # get layer tree layer instance of layer
    layertreelayer = root.findLayer(layer.id())
    
    # get the parent of the layer tree layer (layer tree root, or group)
    parent = layertreelayer.parent()
    
    # if the parent is a group and has a name, find it and remove the layer
    if isinstance(parent, QgsLayerTreeGroup) and parent.name():
        group = root_group.findGroup(parent.name())
        group.removeLayer(layer)
    # remove layers that are not in a group
    else:
        root_group.removeLayer(layer)
        
# update legend
legend.adjustBoxSize()
layout.refresh()
```

Note: there will need to be some extra logic (e.g. recursion) added to deal with sub-groups.

Comment: Hi Matt ! Qgis says "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'removeLayer'". The "group" variable does not seem to be recognized !

Comment: What does `parent.name()` return?

Comment: with print(parent.name()) : The group names of the layers to be removed

Comment: Are any of your groups subgroups (a group within a group)? With 'first level' groups the script works flawlessly when I test it.

Comment: That's weird, I'm only testing the script on first level groups !

Comment: Does it return `False` when you do `root_group.findGroup(parent.name()) == root_group.findGroup('name_of_group')` in the console?

Comment: Actually I restarted QGIS and I don't get the message error anymore. However only the layers from the first group are removed from legend. The layers in the other groups are not removed

Comment: Actually it's working if I check all layers and groups in the layer panel ! It doesn't remove the unchecked ones but I'm going to fix that in the code ! Thanks for your anwser and help !

Comment: Well discovered :) although that doesn't make a difference for me (QGIS 3.28.1). Layer/group visibility can be unchecked but they still react to the script. I'm glad you got it working.